# Oracle:Create new Row while updating old row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hi I am trying create a new row in below while updating old row values.

I have below table called TestCustomer,I would like to update existing row  status to 'I' and create a new row with new email_Id and status "A" if customer_id matches while inserting;

```
create table TestCustomer(customer_id varchar(18),emai_id varchar(18),email_stat char(1))

Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223459','12345','A');
Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223458','123456','I');
Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223459','123457','A');
```

**Input:**

```
customer_id=223459 emai_id='23678'
```

**Output:**

[image]

Output

Comment: It’s challenging to do through value based insert statements. To achieve this ideally you should have the incoming source data in a staging table or something like that.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. In your example data, what happened to customer_id 223458? What do you mean by "if customer id matches while inserting"? Matches what?

Comment: I am updating a new email_id for given customer, in this case 223459.So old email_id associated with customer will be inactive ,and new email id will be active.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using `merge` statement with 2 rows in `using` clause: one for `update` and second for `insert`:

```sql
merge into TestCustomer t
using (
      select
         c,
         223459  as customer_id,
         '23678' as emai_id
      from dual
           ,(select 'A' c from dual union all select 'X' c from dual)
) v
on (v.c='X' and t.customer_id=v.customer_id)
when matched then update
    set email_stat='I'
when not matched then
    insert (customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)
    values(v.customer_id,v.emai_id,v.c)
    where v.c='A';
```

as you can see, the row with 'X' is used for update and the rows with 'A'.

Full example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f014283e5eff2e4cc81d09f0bbfca9b